# Decision tree for continues target variable

Tags: decision-tree

I am trying to build a decision tree in which I have mixed independent variables and continuous dependent variable in r.which decision tree can I apply? I don't want to use CART as I want more than 2 splits.

Comment: Please, show what you have done so far...

Comment: I haven't started with the code

Comment: :) `    ` not many people will start your code for you.. lol

Comment: I'm asking what decision tree will work.coding I will apply

Answer (score 0):

You can use C4.5 algorithm to build your decision tree, he applies to use independent variables and continuous dependent variable, and also you can split more then 2 splits.